# How to add lock by id in python

Tags: python, multithreading

There is a function to get the object by the key, the objects is stored in a dict, if key does not exist, then initialize the object according to the key, then put the key and object to the dict, and return the object , How to ensure in the python multi-thread environment The initialization operation is not repeated when it does not exist, and does not block access to other keys.

Answer (score -1):

locks with similar to any other programming languages.

```
from threading import Lock, Thread
lock = Lock()
g = 0

def add_one(): 
   global g
   lock.acquire()
   g += 1
   lock.release()
```

Comment: here add_one() is any method which is applied with lock and executes some instructions and finally release it. It's one way of performing synchronous operations.

Comment: for more information please read through the blog below https://hackernoon.com/synchronization-primitives-in-python-564f89fee732